# The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values, not a string. Style with multiple property

Tags: reactjs

[image]

```
<div style="background: url('images/slider/slider1.jpg') no-repeat fixed center; height: 100vh;">
```

I have this piece, I have tried to make it become
`<div style={{"background: url('images/slider/slider1.jpg') no-repeat fixed center; height: 100vh"}}>`
[image]
And I tried to change it to `<div style={{background: url('images/slider/slider1.jpg') no-repeat fixed center; height: 100vh}}>`
[image]
Or else I tried it to
`<div style={{"background: url('images/slider/slider1.jpg') no-repeat fixed center, height: '100'vh"}}>`
[image]
It won't work either, I need some little guidance and help, thank you!

Comment: can you try this ? style={{ background: "..... " }} .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to write it like that :

{ background: "all your properties", height: "100vh" }

please have a look at React documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#style

Comment: Thanks, it stops showing the error, I have read it before but can't figure it out, I think I'll read it again.